# IntelliSense for Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I cannot get IntelliSense to work in Visual Studio 2015 Pro for Xamarin Forms.
First, I’m creating a new Project “Cross Platform App (Xamarin.Forms or Native)”. Then I’m editing MainPage.xaml but there is no IntelliSense available at all. When I type I don’t get any help what valid elements are.

I tried adding schemas but nothing changed:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/troubleshooting/questions/enable-axml-intellisense/

I tried opening the xaml file in different kinds of editors but that didn’t do anything either:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64005/intellisense-problem-in-visual-studio

Without IntelliSense Xamarin Forms in VS lose their value to meaningfully create an iOS or Android application of any complexity and we are back to where we were 20 years ago.

Does anybody have information about this issue?

Comment: Is this also a problem in VS2017?

Comment: I had the same problem in Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Comment: @HankTuff, have you already installed the latest VS 2015 with update 3? Meanwhile, go to Tools-Options-Xamarin-Other and click 'Check Now' to check there is any update for Xamarin or not.

Comment: I have VS 2015 with Update 3 and I have all Xamarin updates installed. There has to be something else. It's driving me bonkers.

Comment: I uninstalled Visual Studio 2017 Community and re-installed it. I have version 15.0.26228.9 now. There the IntelliSense is working. Now I need to get it to work in 2015 too.